# How do I install CUDA development headers on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I tried installing the recommended Nvidia driver using the "Additional Drivers" control panel. This results in CUDA being installed according to `nvidia-smi`, but cuda.h is missing. Normally I would obtain it by installing `nvidia-cuda-dev` or `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, but these packages now conflict with nvidia-driver so that they can't both be installed at once:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-encode-515:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-utils-515
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libaccinj64-11.5 libcub-dev libcublas11 libcublaslt11 libcudart11.0 libcufft10 libcufftw10 libcuinj64-11.5 libcupti-dev libcupti-doc libcupti11.5 libcurand10 libcusolver11 libcusolvermg11 libcusparse11 libnppc11 libnppial11
  libnppicc11 libnppidei11 libnppif11 libnppig11 libnppim11 libnppist11 libnppisu11 libnppitc11 libnpps11 libnvblas11 libnvidia-compute-495 libnvidia-compute-510 libnvidia-ml-dev libnvjpeg11 libnvrtc-builtins11.5 libnvrtc11.2
  libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm4 libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev node-html5shiv nsight-compute nsight-compute-target nsight-systems nsight-systems-target nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-toolkit-doc nvidia-opencl-dev
  nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual-profiler ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers opencl-clhpp-headers
```

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: The nvidia-smi show its cuda version support, not that cuda is installed. There are answers here for installing cuda into all non-system directories with the .run file, skipping the Nvidia driver, and avoiding all dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this conflict problem and solved it by installing version 510 of the Nvidia driver.

Alternatively you can install the CUDA toolkit manually instead of using apt-get to keep using version 515: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: That toolkit install doesn't install header files for me.